# How to get duration of specific audio in AudioSourse just_audio Flutter?

Tags: flutter, duration, just-audio

I am building a project can play audios with just_audio.
I have a list of audios put in AudioSource and I need to create a control dash (a play button and a progress bar) for each of audio in the list, instead of using a common for the playlist as usual.
But I have no idea how to get duration/duration stream of each audio in the list and every time I click the play button of a specific audio, only that audio will be played?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFc5b.png)
In the picture, I can only get duration of current state, using player.durationStream, and when I click the play button, only current audio of sequenceState be played.

Please help, tkx a lot!!!

Comment: can you include examples of the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

This feature isn't yet supported, but there is an open feature request for it:

https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/141

However, this may not be what you actually want. Be aware that querying the duration directly from the media file can be inefficient in some cases, and so if you actually know the duration in advance, it may be better for the app to maintain its own local database of metadata which includes the durations:

1. If the audio is coming from a podcast, note that the podcast feed should report a medium-fidelity duration for each item in the XML file, measured in seconds(*).
2. If the audio was recorded by your app, you could save the duration metadata into your database at the same time the recording is made.
3. If the audio is on the device, you can query it using flutter_audio_query.
4. If the audio is an asset packaged with the app, then the durations are known by implication and can also be packaged with the app (i.e. hard coded).

(*) If the podcast feed omitted the duration field, you can still query it by extracting just enough of the audio file to read its duration and then disposing of the temporary player:

```dart
final disposablePlayer = Player();
final duration = await disposablePlayer.setAudioSource(...);
disposablePlayer.dispose();
```

Comment: I finally used a similar solutions as your example code, I created a list of player in initState and then set each member audio in the playlist as audioSource for the corresponding player. Anyway, thank you so much for your hard work!